# How to achieve continuous integration in Perforce?

Tags: continuous-integration, perforce

We use Perforce to manage our Software Configuration.

My question is how to achieve continuous integration in Perforce?
Are there any tools built on top of Perforce to run continuous integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official one is [Electric Cloud](http://www.electric-cloud.com), through its ["Continuous Delivery" feature](http://www.electric-cloud.com/solutions/continuous-delivery.php).  See the [press release from May 2012](http://www.electric-cloud.com/news/2012-0522.php).

However, the tool itself is only one part of the process. The other is how you access the code with Perforce: the blog post ["Massive Automation: Agile, Continuous Integration, and Perforce](http://www.electric-cloud.com/news/2012-0522.php)" details how:

> Automation, particularly at this scale, puts a tremendous load on the SCM server. Build automation can account for well over 50% of the load on a Perforce server, and that can start impacting the end user experience

So it insists on the presence of replica in order to alleviate the charge put on the central Perforce server.

[image: Improved Replication Support for Automation]

You can see another process for CI with Perforce in the article "[Compartmentalized Continuous Integration](http://www.perforce.com/user-conferences/2011/compartmentalized-continuous-integration)".

Answer (score 2):

Perforce has a full list of their Build partners (there are *ahem* many) here:

http://www.perforce.com/product/components/integrations/build_tools

Answer (score 1):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is an awesome and widely used continuous integration tool.
There's a perforce plugin (among lots of other valuable plugins).